# ORACLE regexp_substr extract everything after specific char

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to get rest of string after specific char?

I have a string `'a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|'` and I would like to get result after 3rd occurance of `|`. So the result should be like `2|:x80|3|rr|`

The query

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|','[^|]+$',1,4) 
from dual
```

Returned me NULL

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUBSTR / INSTR` combination

```
WITH t ( s ) AS (
     SELECT 'a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|'
     FROM dual
) SELECT substr(s,instr(s,'|',1,3) + 1)
  FROM t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3bdf105e4555786d4f85032fb7722e00)

Comment: But can you please explain how will be the query if there are other columns as well in the query. I mean for example 
select value1,value2,'a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|' from dual

Comment: @ErkkoKõrgema : I don't understand your confusion. What I've shown is just an example to have the column name aliased as `s` using a CTE. You may replace the `substr` expression with your column name along with other columns in your main select query as usual.

Answer (score 1):

`REGEXP_REPLACE()` will do the trick.  Skip 3 groups of anything followed by a pipe, then replace with the 2nd group, which is the rest of the line (anchored to the end).

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|', '(.*?\|){3}(.*)$', '\2') trimmed
  2  from dual;

TRIMMED
------------
2|:x80|3|rr|

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a nice by long way by using `regexp_substr`, `regexp_count` and `listagg` together as :

```
select listagg(str) within group (order by lvl) 
       as "Result String"
  from
(
  with t(str) as
  (
   select 'a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|' from dual
  )
  select level-1 as lvl,
         regexp_substr(str,'(.*?)(\||$)',1,level) as str 
    from dual
    cross join t
   connect by level <= regexp_count('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|','\|')
)
where lvl >= 3;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/VGCMU66195)

Answer (score 0):

If you use oracle 11g and above you can specify a subexpression to return like this:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|','([^|]+\|){3}(.+)$',1,1,null,2) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Erkko,
You need to use the combination of `SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_INSTR` OR `INSTR`.

Your query will look like this. (Without Regex)
`SELECT SUBSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|',INSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|','|',1,3)+1) from dual;`

Your query will look like this. (With Regex as you want to use)
`SELECT SUBSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|',REGEXP_INSTR('a|b|c|2|:x80|3|rr|','\|',1,3)+1) from dual;`

**Explanation:**

First, you will need to find the place of the string you want as you mentioned. So in your case `|` comes at place 6. So that +1 would be your position to start to substring.

Second, from the original string, substring from that position+1 to unlimited.(Where your string ends)

**Example:**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6fd782db95f575201eded084493232ee